# Simple word count MapReduce example yielding strange results

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hortonworks-data-platform

I am having a strange problem with a Hadoop Map/Reduce job. The job submits correctly, runs, but produces incorrect/strange results. It seems as if the mapper and reducer are not run at all. The input file is transformed from:

```
12
16
132
654
132
12
```

to

```
0   12
4   16
8   132
13  654
18  132
23  12
```

I assume the first column are the generated keys for pairs before the mapper, but neither mapper nor reducer seem to run. The job ran fine when I used the old API.

Source for the job is provided below. I am using Hortonworks as the platform.

```
public class HadoopAnalyzer
{
    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
    {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                context.write(word, one);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
    {
        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values)
            {
                sum += val.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(HadoopAnalyzer.class);
        conf.setJobName("wordcount");
        conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "192.168.229.128:50300");
        conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://192.168.229.128:8020");
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.229.128:8020");
        conf.set("hbase.master", "192.168.229.128:60000");
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.229.128");
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
        System.out.println("Executing job.");
        Job job = new Job(conf, "job");
        job.setInputFormatClass(InputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(OutputFormat.class);
        job.setJarByClass(HadoopAnalyzer.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/user/usr/in"));
        TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/user/usr/out"));
        job.setMapperClass(Mapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }
}
```

Maybe I am missing something obvious, but can anyone shed some light on what might be going wrong here?

Comment: The first dataset - Is that the input or the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is as expected because you used the following,

```
job.setMapperClass(Mapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);
```

Which should have been --

```
job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
```

You extended the Mapper and Reducer classes with Map and Reduce but didn't use them in your job.

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I did that, though. :)